# How to set Ctrl+MMB to Orbit?

Tags: shortcut, customization, navigation

How do i set my <kbd>MMB</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to orbit. What is the hotkey term in keymap settings?

Very much grateful for any suggestions, Stewart

Comment: Just be aware that the Ctrl+MMB is already used for the zoom, so you may want to change that as well or deactivate in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut for *rotate view* can be changed in [user preferences](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/preferences/introduction.html#open-user-preferences). Assuming you are using 2.8 keymap, see the gif below:

[image]

Open user preferences.

Go to keymap section and search for *rotate view* to *middle mouse* in key binding.

Then you may simply change the shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>MMB</kbd> from the default
<kbd>MMB</kbd>

Comment: thanks tim, that works very well:) do u think its possible to click RMB to rotate instead and try in keymap but it just disappears the feather from list?